# Use SBG6580 as a WIFI router?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, bridge

Recently, I moved to a new apartment. 
This is a pre-wired place. All outlets have LAN network. I have been trying to turn my SBG6580 into a simple WIFI router since I do not need to use Comcast Cable anymore. 
For now, I tried to turn primary network into bridge mode. For couple times, SBG 6580 works. The problem is few hours later, WIFI signal is still there but network just down for no reason.

Does anyone have similar problem or have similar attempt?